# Convert column of dates (factor) to day numbers (numeric) in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a R data frame with the following data:

```
         date    x
  2012-10-01     0
  2012-10-02   126
  2012-10-03 11352
  2012-10-04 12116
  2012-10-05 13294
  2012-11-01 15420
  2012-11-02 11015
  2012-11-03     0
  2012-11-04 12811
```

The values in the `date` column are factors, while the values in the `x` column are numeric. I would like to convert the values in the `date` column to numeric. However, I want the date to be replaced by a number, so that each value corresponds to its row index. E.g. the result should be the following:

```
             date  x
             1     0
             2   126
             3 11352
             4 12116
             5 13294
             6 15420
             7 11015
             8     0
             9 12811
```

However, I am not sure what is the best way to go about doing this. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: `df$date <- 1:nrow(df)`

Comment: It doesn't seem like the date values themselves are at all relevant. You seem to to want to add a new column with a sequential number for each row.

Comment: Are dates unique? If yes, maybe use `df$data <- as.numeric(date)`